# How to fadein fadeout the relative link within each list element please

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout

I'm new to jQuery, I'm trying to make a simple fadein fadeout animation to make in practice what I've learned so far, unfortunately  I'm not getting the result that I want
I have a list elements, within each li element there is a link: 
What I want: when I roll over a li element, I want the relative `<a>` link to fade in and when I roll out I want it to fade out.  This is my code below:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.viewAllProductsLink").hide();
    $(".scrollable ul>li").each(function(){

        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $("a.viewAllProductsLink").fadeIn("slow");    
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $("a.viewAllProductsLink").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$('a.viewAllProductsLink')` you're selecting all of the links with that class when what you want to do is select only the link within the element you're rolling over.  To do that, use `$(this).find()`:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.viewAllProductsLink").hide();
    $(".scrollable ul>li").each(function(){

        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).find("a.viewAllProductsLink").fadeIn("slow");  
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find("a.viewAllProductsLink").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    }); 
});
```

Furthermore, it's innefficient to use `.each()` here since all of the elements will behave the same, and you probably want to use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before the animation to keep the animation queue from building up when you hover over and off the element many times quickly:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.viewAllProductsLink").hide();
    $(".scrollable ul>li").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).find("a.viewAllProductsLink").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");  
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find("a.viewAllProductsLink").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: yeah it works sir ,Thank's for the quick response .  based on your expreience what's the best way to start diving into jquery ,i'm reading jquery in action book ,but i feel kind of lost ,so is there some advices plz

Comment: I learned by using this site and by sifting through http://api.jquery.com and implementing and experimenting with all of the examples using http://jsfiddle.net ... among other things, but that should be plenty to do.  Getting a good foundation in actual Javascript will go a long way as well.

Comment: Thank's ,i'll try to stick to these two sites ,jquery official site and the jsfiddle .